# iPhone Touch ID prompt not displaying french Text for - Touch ID for - "app name" label

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have integrated Touch ID using Cordova TouchID plugin in my hybrid application. Prompt is displaying label proper in English when device language is English but when i changed it to French it is still displaying english text for Touch ID prompt (Touch ID for - "App name") in some devices.

Expected result is it should display "App name" in french.
We observed that its working fine in iPhone 6+ with OS-8.0.2 but not working in iPhone 5s, 6plus with other OS versions.

What needs to do to display localized text for Touch ID prompt?

Comment: Have you changed both region and language or only one of it. If so, which one?

Comment: I have changed both Region and Language but same issue. One thing i observed that for IOS 8.0.2 getting property _creatorDisplayname in LAContext which is working with french but for IOS 9.0+ this property is not available